# Can I short-circuit the traits in this condition?

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Consider the below:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename E>
using is_scoped_enum = std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    std::is_enum_v<E> && !std::is_convertible_v<E, std::underlying_type_t<E>>
>;

template <typename E>
constexpr auto is_scoped_enum_v = is_scoped_enum<E>::value;void foo() {}



class Foo {};
enum Bar {};
enum class Baz {};

//static_assert(!is_scoped_enum_v<Foo>);
static_assert(!is_scoped_enum_v<Bar>);
static_assert(is_scoped_enum_v<Baz>);
```

The commented-out line breaks the build, because `Foo` is not an enum and therefore does not have an underlying type. Of course, `&&` (even though it's in a constant expression) doesn't short-circuit the need for `std::underlying_type_t<E>` to be valid.

Do I need to create some monstrosity of tagged types and chained enable_if, or is there some trivial fix I'm missing?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Ah, that's better 

Comment: Oops, soz, the system nuked your comment when I accepted the other Q as a dupe ‍♂️

Comment: No worries.  If you're happy with it as a dupe that's all we need.

Comment: Yep deffo. I actually looked at that Q before, but the code is so similar to what I already had, I assumed I had indeed originally just taken that code, and didn't look any closer. Should have spotted that it was literally the same approach but... well, fixed ... which is what I wanted. :) Thanks!

Comment: meh didnt see that it was duped. here is basically the same as in the dupes answer applied for your example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kTIB6SnvhVgReUHF

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Nice one